# execute a gui application from the command line and send it to the background

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Is there a command line utility that I can use for executing X based applications that will detach my applications from the terminal so they aren't closed if the terminal is closed?

I guess such a app could be called something like `gnome-run` if it existed.

I have tried `dtach`, but it seems that you have to provide a socket file which is a bit clunky to type.  I have also tried `nohup`, but found that also to be a bit clunky to type by the time std out and err are redirected to `/dev/null`.

I guess I'm looking for a simple program that will do something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it: first you need to run your GUI app and send it to background, then you (probably) want to detach it from Bash task management. For example if I wanted to run gedit this way:

```
gedit &
disown %1
```

After that you can close your terminal window and gedit will not be killed. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You already wrote your program, it is called a shell script and you give it the name you like and put it somewhere. Then you either add that directory to your $PATH or in your bashrc you set:

```
alias gnome-run=<path>/my-awesome-script.sh
```

Why waste earth's resources on a program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an application (say, gedit) **as if it was run from the GUI**, use:

```
xdg-open /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop
```

See [this](https://superuser.com/a/295961/727679) answer on superuser.